# error installing vlc through terminal

Tags: command-line, apt

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: welcome to ask Ubuntu. could you give the command you were trying at the time. did u add sudo bedore the comand? and made sudo apt-get update before it too?

Comment: yeah i've used the above error occured

Comment: @TejaKnv what I mean is what is the command u used to install vlc?

Answer (score 0):

Thumb Rule -
Never use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> to terminate/Stop any process, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.
You might have stopped some apt-get process running or its still running in some other window/terminal.

You can remove the locks using below commands -

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock   
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Then try -

```
apt-get update
```